# Why doesn't the program inherit the signal dispositions of bash?

Tags: c, bash, unix, signals, solaris

I use the following C program to test signal behaviors on `Solaris 10`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        sleep(100);
        return 0;
}
```

Run it in command line:

```
bash-3.2# ./test
```

Then use `psig` to check the signal behaviors of the `test` process:

```
bash-3.2# psig 11918
11918:  ./test
HUP     default
......
CONT    default
TTIN    default
TTOU    default
......
```

All the signal dispositions are `default`.

Use `grep` command to get the parent process of `test`:

```
 root 11918 17894   0 15:28:41 pts/25      0:00 ./test
```

Then use `psig` to check the signal behaviors of the parent of `test` process (`bash`):

```
bash-3.2# psig 17894          
17894:  bash
......
QUIT    ignored
......
TTIN    ignored
TTOU    ignored
......
```

Per my understanding, I think the `bash` should call `fork` to generate `test`, according to [fork](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/fork.2.html), the child process should inherit the signal dispositions.
Why doesn't the program inherit the signal dispositions of `bash`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Catched signals behaviour is not inherited across `exec()`. But OpenGroup's `exec` manual says :

> Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process
>   image shall be set to the default action in the new process image.
>   Except for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling
>   process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image.

So your process signal behaviour is such because `bash` set it so before `exec`ing; which is reasonable.

Comment: How can I verify that is `bash` change the signal behaviors of `test`?

Comment: To confirm, look in the bash source - it is open source after all.